# How to manage uniqueness of a value that is stored in multiple databases tables

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have separate assets tables for storing different kind of physical and logical assets, such as:-

1. Vehicle table( ID, model, EngineSize, Drivername, lastMaintenanceDate)
2. Server table ( ID, IP, OSName, etc…)
3. VM  (ID, Size, etc…).
4. VM_IP (VM_ID,IP)

Now the problems I have is:-

1. For the IP column in the server table and in the VM_IP table, I need this column to be unique in these two tables, so for example the database should not allow a server and a VM to have the same IP. In the current design I can only guarantee uniqueness for the table separately.
   So can anyone advice on how I can handle this unique requirement on the databases level.

Regards

**::EDITED::**

I have currently the following database structure:-

[image]

Currently I see these points:-

1. I have introduced a redundant AssetTypeID column in the base Asset table, so I can know the asset type without having to join tables. This might break normalization.
2. In my above architecture , I cannot control (on the database level) which asset should have IP, which asset should not have IP and which asset can/cannot have multiple IPs.
   So is there a way to improve my architecture to handle these two points.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Create an IP table and use foreign keys

Comment: you mean it is better ,, than using Indexed view as mentioned in the below reply.

Comment: Better? Well a view with a clustered index is "almost" a table anyway. I believe a separate table is more straightforward/simple.

Answer (score 1):

If I were facing the problem in design level, I would add two more tables:

1. A `valid_IP` table (containing valid IP range)
2. A `Network_Enabeled`, base table for all entities that may have an
   IP, like Server table, VM_IP ,... the primary key of this base
   table will be the primary key of child tables.

In Network_Enabeled table, Having a foreign key from valid_IP table and setting a unique key on the filed will be the answer. 
Hope be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [indexed view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16314455/110933).

```
CREATE VIEW YourViewName with SCHEMABINDING
as
    ...
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_YourIndexName
    on YourViewName  (..., ...)
```

Comment: And how are you going to get values from those two tables to appear as the same column in this view, when you're not allowed `UNION`?

Comment: @Damien:maybe by creating another (not indexed) view that uses UNION and which references my indexed view.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edit, you can introduce a superkey on the asset table and use various constraints to enforce most of what it sounds like you're looking for:

```
create table Asset (
    AssetID int not null primary key,
    AssetTypeID int not null
    --Skip all of the rest, foreign keys, etc, irrelevant to example
    ,constraint UQ_Asset_TypeCheck
        UNIQUE (AssetID,AssetTypeID) --This is the superkey
)
```

The above means that the `AssetTypeID` column can now be checked/enforced in other tables, and there's no risk of inconsistency

```
create table Servers (
    AssetID int not null primary key,
    AssetTypeID as 1 persisted,
    constraint FK_Servers_Assets FOREIGN KEY (AssetID)
        references Asset (AssetID), --Strictly, this will become redundant
    constraint FK_Servers_Assets_TypeCheck FOREIGN KEY (AssetID,AssetTypeID)
        references Asset (AssetID,AssetTypeID)
)
```

So, in the above, we enforce that all entries in this table must actually be of the correct asset type, by making it a fixed computed column that is then used in a foreign key back to the superkey.

```
--So on for other asset types
create table Asset_IP (
    AssetID int not null,
    IPAddress int not null primary key, --Wrong type, for IPv6
    AssetTypeID int not null,
    constraint FK_Asset_IP_Assets FOREIGN KEY (AssetID)
        references Asset (AssetID), --Again, redundant
    constraint CK_Asset_Types CHECK (
        AssetTypeID in (1/*,  Other types allowed IPs */)),
    constraint FK_Asset_IP_Assets_TypeCheck FOREIGN KEY (AssetID,AssetTypeID)
        references Asset (AssetID,AssetTypeID)
)
```

And now, above, we again reference the superkey to ensure that we've got a local (to this table) correct `AssetTypeID` value, which we can then use in a check constraint to limit which asset types are actually allowed entries in this table.

```
create unique index UQ_Asset_SingleIPs on Asset_IP (AssetID)
   where AssetTypeID in (1/* Type IDs that are only allowed 1 IP address */)
```

And finally, for certain `AssetTypeID` values, we ensure that this table only contains one row for that `AssetID`.

I hope that gives you enough ideas of how to implement your various checks based on types. If you want/need to, you can now construct some views (through which the rest of your code will interact) which hides the extra columns and provides triggers to ease `INSERT` statements.

On a side note, I'd recommend picking a convention and sticking to it when it comes to table naming. My preferred one is to use the plural/collective name, unless the table is only intended to contain one row. So I'd rename `Asset` as `Assets`, for example, or `Asset_IP` as `Asset_IPs`. At the moment, you have a mixture.